# Problem with sqlite3 and linking in makefile

Tags: c++, sqlite, makefile, linker

I have a project in which I use sqlite3 library in order to create a database. The files are as follows:

```
| sqlite3  
    | shell.c  
    | sqlite3.c  
    | sqlite3.h  
    | sqlite3ext.h  
| database.hpp  
| database.cpp  
| main.cpp  
| makefile
```

And in database.hpp file I do `#include "sqlite3/sqlite3.h"`.
Here is the make file that I wrote for this project:

```
FLAGS = -g 

LIBS = -lsqlite3

CC = g++ 
executable = a.out

all: $(executable)

$(executable): database.o main.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(LIBS) database.o main.cpp -o $(executable)

database.o: database.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(LIBS) -c database.cpp -o database.o

.PHONY : clean

clean: 
    rm $(executable) *.o
```

The problem is that this makefile works just fine in my linux manjaro computer but when I run it in another computer that uses ubuntu, the make sends me errors like `undefined refrence` or sometimes in another machin with ubuntu it sends me `can't find -lsqlite3`.
What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you in advanced for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the system SQLite libraries instead of the ones you shipped.
The simplest solution is to define a new rule for `sqlite3.o` and depend on it in your executable:

```
CFLAGS = -g
CXXFLAGS += $(CFLAGS)
LDFLAGS = -g
# SQLite needs these libraries.
LIBS = -lpthread -ldl
# see https://sqlite.org/howtocompile.html. I added one option to show how it's done
SQLITE3_OPTIONS = -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1

executable = a.out

all: $(executable)

$(executable): database.o sqlite3.o main.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) $^ -o $@

# No rule is necessary for main.o or database.o, these are covered by
# Make's built-in rules

sqlite3.o: sqlite3/sqlite3.c sqlite3/sqlite3.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -Isqlite3 $(SQLITE3_OPTIONS) -c -o $@ $<

.PHONY : clean

clean: 
    rm $(executable) *.o
```

Comment: I am always getting undefined refrence from sqlite3.c file

Comment: Nevermind . Found the problem. I changed the sqlite3.o rule to `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -Isqlite3 $(SQLITE3_OPTIONS) -o $@ -c $<`

Comment: That won't do anything.  Libraries are not used at all during compilation.  What you need to do is put the `$(LIBS)` variable _after_ all the object files (`$^`) in your _linker recipe_.  So it should be: `$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)`.  The libraries should always come last on the link line.